# is it possible to create a dropdown using only html and css without using list tags

Tags: html, css

I have heard that there are features in HTML5 and CSS3 to implement a dropdown list which expands on hover, without using list tags such as  and .

But I am very confused as to how exactly go about it.
Is it something related to flex ?

Comment: You can use any element you wish (within reason) when creating dropdowns. There's no reason why you couldn't use div tags or spans... It's just that lists are more semantic. I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, maybe have a look through a tutorial and see how you go? http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-a-dropdown-menu-with-html-css

Comment: Is your goal tho build a costume, own dropdown without using the select? I don't really understand what you want to do? Explain this please a little bit closer. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: Can you please give us an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a dropdown only with HTML, CSS3 and DIVs without lists and without javascript, jquery etc. I hope this is alright for you. Cheers :)

```css
.mainMenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.mainMenu:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #2f6992;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 150px;
}

.subMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.subMenu:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainMenu">
  <span class="title">HOVER HERE...</span>
  <div class="subMenu">Menu 1</div>
  <div class="subMenu">Menu 2</div>
  <div class="subMenu">Menu 3</div>
</div>
```